# relations between log levels and stdErr/stdOut

Tags: java, logging, stdout, stderr

i read many informations on the net but i'd like to summarize,
and still no understand how it works.
I'd like to know the relation betwenn log levels and stdOut vs stdErr in java ?

what about these kinds of logs ?

```
  logger.trace(..
  logger.warn(..
  logger.error(..
```

what do these logs go ?

i absolutly don't see relation between java logs and stdOut/stdErr.

Thanks by advance.

Comment: Logger generate log messages with those Level.ERROR/WARN/INFO and such. In the comfiguration you could add a log handler with a file appender, and/or format and send the message of some level and name to stderr. The developer normally has a more verbous logging, and sometime activates TRACE to check code execution. Learn using it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very briefly:

Loggers are part of a high level logging framework. Logging is much more advanced than standard output streams.

When a process starts up the operating system gives it a stdout and stderr stream which the program may write to. Stdout should be used for information and stderr for error information.

This is much lower level and you can access these streams with the System class:

```
System.out.println(); // Write to stdout
System.err.println(); // Write to stderr
```

Answer (score 1):

Any connection is based on how you configure the logging framework.

The logging framework maintains a list of *appenders*, which send output to a destination. That destination may be stdout, stderr, a file, a TCP connection to some remote server, or many other places. When you call `logger.debug()`, the logging framework will look at its list of configured appenders, and pass the message on to any appenders that are accepting debug-level messages.

You don't say what logging framework you're using, but assuming Log4J 2.x you are probably using the [ConsoleAppender](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#ConsoleAppender). This can be configured to send output to *either* StdErr or StdOut:

```
  <Appenders>
    <Console name="CONSOLE" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
      <PatternLayout pattern="%m%n"/>
    </Console>
  </Appenders>
```

```
  <Appenders>
    <Console name="CONSOLE" target="SYSTEM_ERR">
      <PatternLayout pattern="%m%n"/>
    </Console>
  </Appenders>
```